# File as an S-Corp to retain deductions after new US tax bill

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

According to https://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2017/11/28/small-businesses-cast-jaundiced-eye-at-tax-reform-proposals/, should the current tax reform bill pass into law: "corporations would continue to be able to write off state and local tax deductions, while the owners of pass-through entities—the vast majority of all small businesses—would not".

So if I simply file my LLC's taxes as an S-Corp, will I be able to continue to take the deductions that are being taken away from pass-through entities? Or would I need to re-register the company as an S-Corp first?